# C# Textbox Keypress Event?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I was wondering how can I make the textbox only accepts less than or equal to a number?

I have this keypress event for my textbox

```
//**This will select and count the number of rows for a certain topic**

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(CONTENT) FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = '" + topic + "'";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dAdap.Fill(dTable);

private void txtNo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    topic = cmbTopic.Text;

    //**This is to get the cell value of the DataTable**
    int total = Int32.Parse(dTable.Rows[0][0].ToString());

    //**Int32.Parse(txtNo.Text) >= total, convert the txtNo.Text to integer and compare it to total (total number of rows), ideally**
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && Int32.Parse(txtNo.Text) >= total

    {
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play(); //**Plays a beep sound to alert an error**
        e.Handled = true; //**Prevent the character from being entered**
    }
}
```

For my IF statement, the user is only allowed to input a numeric/integer and must be less than or equal to a number. And when I run the program, yes it doesn't accept other characters except a number, but I can input greater than the total number.

Comment: Side note: you should stop for a second and think how user actually would  be able to enter anything if code works as you want it too... (Hint to enter 10 one types 1, 0).

Comment: Use `NumericUpdown` control.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, gonna read about that control

Comment: Just drop in on your form and set `Minimum` and `Maximum` property of it simply using designer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, lol I was thinking that NumericUpDown is an event. thanks for pointing this one.

Comment: Oh! You didn't read **Control** in the comment! :D You're welcome :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I have an issue with the control. numRnd.Maximum = total; in this condition yes the control will set the maximum value to total if I use the up control. But when I use the keyboard, I can type larger than the total.

Comment: But if you check the `Value` property, it will never be greater than `Maximum` and as soon as you leave the control, the `Text` will revert to `Maximum` if it's greater.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, yes it does. tried using messagebox to check it. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few minor mistakes in your code (which I fixed for you), the biggest problem however was, that you didn't check the value of the textBox *after* you entered the number but before - hence the user could enter one character more than allowed. It seems to work like that though:

```
private void txtNo_KeyPress (object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    topic = cmbTopic.Text;

    //**This is to get the cell value of the DataTable**
    int total = Int32.Parse (dTable.Rows [0] [0].ToString ());

    //**Int32.Parse(txtNo.Text) >= total, convert the txtNo.Text to integer and compare it to total (total number of rows), ideally**
    if (!char.IsControl (e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit (e.KeyChar) || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && txtNo.Text.Length > 0 && Int32.Parse (txtNo.Text + e.KeyChar) > total)

    {
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play (); //**Plays a beep sound to alert an error**
        e.Handled = true; //**Prevent the character from being entered**
    }
}
```